# Permissions issue in Linux with root vs other admin acct

Tags: linux, directory, permissions, chmod

I know there are many different examples on here, but I am having trouble with my specific example.

I am trying to copy some files from a specific folder on my Windows PC to my VPS (Virtual Private Server) by using SSH via WinSCP.

The folder that was created looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are permissions as root as the owner.  I login as a different user named Smith.  When I try to transfer files from the PC to the folder, I get access denied.
A few things I tried:

- I deactivated root for security purposes so I can't easily login as root.  I could reactivate it temporarily to do this exercise, but trying to find a different way.
- Even though Smith is an Admin, that account can't seem to move files to this directory when logging in
- I tried sudo -i for root but root doesn't share any groups with Smith and not sure what to do other than making it 777
- I know I can just blow out security and make it 777, but I am guessing that's bad practice?

Maybe I missed something in what I did above, but what's the best way so that Smith can copy files to the directory above when logged in as Smith, even though there are no groups shared with root that could be used right now, and I don't want to just blow security wide open?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: By the time I saw this there was an answer, and now it's threatening to never let me ask another question ever ever again so I can't delete.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to write the directory as the user `Smith`, then the simplest solution is probably to make `Smith` the owner of the directory. Assuming you can login to a Linux console with `sudo` permissions, you can deploy that using a command something like:

```bash
$ sudo chown Smith bookstore
```